# Drupal go to with destination

Tags: users

I have a page with two links visible to people, but on clicking  of either of two, user needs to log in to view, so in case user is not logged in, i am sending users to login page with `drupal_goto('user')`, i want that if the user clicked 1st link and is redirected to login page, after successful login, he should be redirected again to that 1st link 
i tried with this code but did not work,

```
$query = array('destination' => 'node/id');
drupal_goto('user',$query);
```

Comment: @googletorp has provided an answer. If you are trying to create a link to the login form that would send the user back to the current page, see if  `drupal_get_destination` works better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `drupal_goto` the same way you use `url`.

So what you need to do is this:

```
$query = array('destination' => 'node/id');
drupal_goto('user', array('query' => $query));
```